# Why can I allocate a local variable and fread to it, but segfault if I try to allocate a pointer in a struct and read to it?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm playing with a small C program to brush up.  I have the following struct...

```
struct Address {
    int id;
    int set;
    char *name;
    char *email;
};
```

I am trying to read some data into it.  This works:

```
size_t len = 256 * sizeof(char);

struct Address *thisAddress = malloc(sizeof(struct Address));
char *name = malloc(len);
char *email = malloc(len);

rc = fread(thisAddress, sizeof(struct Address), 1, conn->file);
if(rc != 1) die("Failed to load address.", conn);

rc = fread(name, len, 1, conn->file);
if(rc != 1) die("Failed to load name.", conn);

rc = fread(email, len, 1, conn->file);
if(rc != 1) die("Failed to load email.", conn);

thisAddress->name = name;
thisAddress->email = email;
conn->db->rows[i] = thisAddress;
```

But this segfaults:

```
size_t len = 256 * sizeof(char);
struct Address *thisAddress = malloc(sizeof(struct Address));
thisAddress->name = malloc(len);
thisAddress->email = malloc(len);

rc = fread(thisAddress, sizeof(struct Address), 1, conn->file);
if(rc != 1) die("Failed to load address.", conn);

rc = fread(thisAddress->name, len, 1, conn->file);
if(rc != 1) die("Failed to load name.", conn);

rc = fread(thisAddress->email, len, 1, conn->file);
if(rc != 1) die("Failed to load email.", conn);

conn->db->rows[i] = thisAddress;
```

If you can't see it right away, in the first one I'm malloc'ing the name and edit vars, reading from the file into those vars, then assigning them to the name and email pointers on struct Address.  In the second, I'm trying to alloc the pointers on struct Address, and read directly into them.

Why would these two be different?  Any insight is helpful, thanks!

Comment: `malloc(strlen)`? What? Are you trying to use the `strlen` *function*, or do you shadow the function with a variable with the same name? And what is the value of that variable? Please try to create a [Minimal, *Complete*, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I'm not sure I understand suggesting changes to the question, and then proceeding to answer it.

Comment: Other less experienced people will sooner or later find your question, not seeing a nice MCVE, and especially seeing a common function being used as a variable will be very confusing for them. This site is not only to get an answer to your current problem, but also to help others with similar (or the same) problem in the future.

Comment: Hi guys, sorry about that.  Poor choice of variable name that was set outside the block and hence missed the copy-paste.  My fault.  I updated to make a bit more readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you do

```
thisAddress->name = malloc(len);
thisAddress->email = malloc(len);
```

Then you do

```
rc = fread(thisAddress, sizeof(struct Address), 1, conn->file);
```

This reading of the structure *overwrites* the pointers you previously set. So the pointers you use to read the name and email address texts from the file are not the ones you allocated, but the ones you read from the file, which are very unlikely to point to any valid memory, leading to *undefined behavior*.

If you change the order of the first structure read and the allocations it should work.

Comment: I was afraid of this, but reading the man page says "The function fread() reads nitems objects, each size bytes long, from the stream pointed to by stream, storing them at the location given by ptr."  This leads me to believe that the buffer being read should be copied to the memory address pointed to by the input ptr.  If this is the case, then I don't understand why the pointer itself would be overwritten.

Comment: @Herm `sizeof(struct Address)` is the complete size of the structure, including the `name` and `email` members. So when you tell `fread` to read one element of `sizeof(struct Address)` bytes, then it will do that and write all the bytes it read to the pointer given by `thisAddress`. What's in the file is most likely not very valid pointers for the current process, leading to *undefined behavior* when you use the pointers. The solution is, like I said, just to move the allocations to after you read the structure.

Comment: AH!!! I totally get that now!  That really helps to clarify!  I was looking at your original comment incorrectly before.  Thank you!